# Why my state is not not defined?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Below is es5 syntax

```
function customMsg(state, action) {
     state = state || {};
    return $.extend({}, state, {
       isFetching: false,
        didInvalidate: false,
        checkStatus: checkStatus(state.checkStatus, action)
     });
}

function checkStatus(state, action) {
    state = state || {
        isFetching: false,
        didInvalidate: false,  
        type: "room"
    };
        return state;
    }
}
```

Below is es6 syntax

```
const initialStae = {
    isFetching: false,
    didInvalidate: false,
    checkStatus: checkStatus(state.checkStatus, action)
}

function customMsg(state = initialStae, action) {
    return state;
}

function checkStatus(state, action) {
    state = state || {
        isFetching: false,
        didInvalidate: false,  
        type: "room"
    };

    return state;
}
```

Why my line 7 will show "state is not defined" from es6?

```
customMsgReducer.js:36Uncaught ReferenceError: state is not defined(…)
```

Comment: `mailContent: mailContent(state.mailContent, action)` `state` should be undefined here

Comment: Can you please add the full error message you get.

Comment: @aBloomer your `state` is still undefined at moment of defining `initialStae`

Comment: @aBloomer you can only access the redux state inside reducer/actions and MapStateToProps function

Answer (score 1):

In ES5, you define `state = state || {};` and then accessing `state.checkStatus`. Hence its working.

```
function customMsg(state, action) {
     state = state || {};
    return $.extend({}, state, {
       isFetching: false,
        didInvalidate: false,
        checkStatus: checkStatus(state.checkStatus, action)
     });
}
```

But in ES6, you access `state.checkStatus` without defining the `state` which is `undefined` here. Hence accessing `checkStatus` of `undefined` is throwing error.